# T-SQL Job Scheduler

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Disclaimer: I wouldn't be at all surprised to find out this is duplicate somewhere, but I have literally been searching for hours. All I can find it DBA information that I don't believe pertains to what I am trying to accomplish.

I am currently developing a small database for a friends startup. He has jobs that he needs to track that are performed on regular intervals (e.g. semi-annually, annually, quarterly, weekly, etc.).

I am trying to wrap my mind around how I can implement a solution in sql server where a customer has 0 to many tasks, and a specific task can have 0 many customers. Seems simple enough, but I also want to keep a history for each time the task was completed for each customer where it is assigned. This would be a record with a scheduled task and a completed date. Lastly, I need to be able to execute a query to retrieve upcoming scheduled tasks within a given period of time (e.g. all scheduled jobs coming up next month).

I know that there are is a ton of software that does stuff like this, so it can't be that uncommon, but I cannot find any information that is getting me anywhere. If there are any resources anyone could recommend it would greatly appreciated.

Comment: "a customer has 0 to many tasks, and a specific task can have 0 many customers" this is commonly called a "many-to-many relationship", or "n:m relationship". Some googling of these terms should point you in the right direction. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a table to hold all the list of tasks that need to be done, with columns where you can later record when they have been done.

You can easily then just query it to find what needs to be done.

Then create a stored procedure that does the work. Have the procedure do the right thing for different periods i.e. monthly, etc. Have it just work out what's needed, and do it.

Create a single SQL Server Agent job that runs that procedure each month. (Or however often it's needed).

As you do each step, no-one's going to mind if you ask for help with each part i.e. get comments on your table when you first design it, etc. (Or at least I wouldn't mind - some might but ignore them)